# nested namespace route going to wrong controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, routes, nested-routes

Using Rails 3.0.7, I'm creating an API for our app, and I have this setup:

routes.rb

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      match "connect" => "users#login", :via => :post
      match "disconnect" => "users#logout", :via => :post
      resources :users
      match "users/:id/foos" => "foos#list", :via => :get
      match "users/:id" => "users#update", :via => :put
      match "foos/:id/bars" => "bars#list_by_foo", :via => :get
      match "foos/:id" => "foos#show", :via => :get, :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }
      match "bars/:id" => "bars#show", :via => :get
    end
  end

  # other routes here e.g.
  match "users/find" => "users#find_by_name", :via => :get
  match "users" => "users#create", :via => :post
```

And then I have my regular `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` files as well as my `app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb` and `app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb` files that are defined like the following:

```
class Api::V1::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :verify_access

  def verify_access
    # some code here
  end
end

class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter, :except => [:show, :update, :delete]
end
```

And before everything seemed to be working right until I overrode a method that is shared by both UsersController and Api::V1::UsersController -- and now it seems like everything is pointing to UsersController even though I'm accessing through the api/v1/users route.

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks. PS - feel free to comment with whatever conventions I'm ignoring that I shouldn't be or other things I might have messed up :)

Comment: Turns out I just had to make all my controller names unique, regardless of namespace. [Here's a link that helped](http://blog.philburrows.com/articles/2008/05/02/rails-namespaces-rock-rails-namespaces-suck-/)

Answer (score 0):

`skip_before_filter` also general takes a symbol parameter for the before filter than you wish to skip. Controller names should not have to be unique as long as the proper scoping/namespacing is applied.

example

- api/users_controller
- admin/users_controller
- users_controller

then the code per controller

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseController
end

class Admin:UsersController < Admin::BaseController
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```

Then the routes

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

scope :module => "api" do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end

namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails is a bit confusing, but I had a similar problem. Here's some steps you can take to make sure you're not missing any small code issues. (this eventually led me to discover a syntax bug in the namespaced controller).

1. run `bundle exec rake routes` to generate a list of what route links to what controller and action. If this is good, then move to step 2. If not, fix your routes file and try again. (many good tutorials on this, so I won't go into detail)
2. Go into the rails console, and just load the controller class. If it doesn't work, you may have discovered a bug in syntax. Here's what happened on console when I tried to load the `Api::V2::CampaignsController`.

   irb> Api::V2::CampaignsController

   => CampaignsController

Note: Rails is directing all requests to the wrong controller (based on Rails' fancy logic to load controller classes). It should goto Api::V2::CampaignsController, but instead it is loading CampaignsController.

You can also verify it in the console with:

```
> app.get '/api/v2/campaigns.json'
> app.controller.class
=> CampaignsController
# This is not the expected controller.
```

This ended up being a syntax problem in a class I was extending from the Api::V2::CampaignsController.

It was a bit mind-boggling, but hope this helps someone else.