# Rails namespaced routes to wrong Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm just beginning with RoR and figured I do a basic blog with API endpoints aswell. The problem is that my api requests seem to be routed to the wrong controller,

I have the following as my routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :articles
    end
  end

end
```

I also have `controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb`, which has the following content:

```
module API
  module V1    
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def index
        respond_with Article.all
      end

    end
  end
end
```

My logic says that when I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/articles`, this should be the Controller to respond, however the actual Controller that responds is the one in the root of controllers (`controllers/articles_controller.rb`) and not the one in the `/api/v1` path. When I remove the Controller that actually responds, I'll get `uninitialized constant Api::V1::ArticlesController` instead.

Even `rake routes` gives me the expected routes, however actually hitting those endpoints fails. Output of `rake routes` is the following:

```
api_v1_articles GET    /api/v1/articles(.:format)          api/v1/articles#index
                    POST   /api/v1/articles(.:format)          api/v1/articles#create
 new_api_v1_article GET    /api/v1/articles/new(.:format)      api/v1/articles#new
edit_api_v1_article GET    /api/v1/articles/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/articles#edit
     api_v1_article GET    /api/v1/articles/:id(.:format)      api/v1/articles#show
                    PUT    /api/v1/articles/:id(.:format)      api/v1/articles#update
                    DELETE /api/v1/articles/:id(.:format)      api/v1/articles#destroy
```

The only similar question I found on SO is [nested namespace route going to wrong controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457076/nested-namespace-route-going-to-wrong-controller) however, there's no accepted answer there and it's been a year. Maybe another attempt will help resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module is `API`, but Rails is looking for `Api`. Ruby's modules are case-sensitive.

Comment: I would have never noticed that myself. Thanks