# Namespaced route going to wrong (parent) controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, url-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

There are some other Qs ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457076/nested-namespace-route-going-to-wrong-controller) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798135/rails-namespaced-routes-to-wrong-controller)) but unfortunately they don't help.

I have an event resource, and a namespaced event_participant. The routes, actions, etc look good, but when I attempt to click a link_to to my custom, namespaced action the route is mapped to the events#update controller. No idea what's going wrong!

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events
  namespace :events do
      put "/:id/add_or_rm_role" => "participants#add_or_rm_role"
  end
end
```

rake routes

```
          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
          events GET    /events(.:format)                    events#index
                 POST   /events(.:format)                    events#create
       new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                events#new
      edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)           events#edit
           event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                events#show
                 PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                events#update
                 PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                events#update
                 DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                events#destroy
                 PUT    /events/:id/add_or_rm_role(.:format) events/participants#add_or_rm_role #This one looks good!
```

participants_controller.rb

```
class ParticipantsController::EventsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def add_or_rm_role
    event = Event.find(event_participants_params.event_id)
    #add user role to event...
    redirect_to event, notice: 'Changes have been saved!'
  end

  private
    def event_participants_params
      params.permit(:role, :is_add, :event_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

The events_controller.rb is the autogenerated one.

The link_to on events/show is

```
    <%= link_to "Sign Up For Event", 
        event_path(role: Event::Participant.event_role_types[:participant], is_add: false, id: @event.id),
        action: :add_or_rm_role,
        method: :put, remote: true %>
```

When I click the link, the following PUT request is sent. You can see it is processing the wrong link as the wrong format. The link_to is a little button that adds the current_user as a participant to a given event.

```
Started PUT "/events/_ceEY?is_add=false&role=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 20:05:10 -0400
Processing by EventsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"is_add"=>"false", "role"=>"3", "id"=>"_ceEY"}
#......
```

Any idea on what wires are getting cross here?

**UPDATE**

The following answers suggest using a nested route instead of a namespaced one, but I'd like to keep trying to get namespaced routes to work to improve my organization/file structure in my controller. Switching to nested will be the nuclear option, but I'd like to see where this takes me first. Utilizing the current feedback I have made the following changes:

config/routes.rb

```
#...
  namespace :events do
      put :add_or_rm_role, to: 'participants#add_or_rm_role'
  end
```

rake routes

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
   #...
   events_add_or_rm_role PUT    /events/add_or_rm_role(.:format) events/participants#add_or_rm_role
```

link_to

```
    <%= link_to "Sign Up For Event", 
        events_add_or_rm_role_path(role: Event::Participant.event_role_types[:participant], is_add: false, event_id: @event.id),
        method: :put, remote: true %>
```

events/participants_controller.rb

```
class Events::ParticipantsController < ApplicationController #Renamed
  #...
  def event_participants_params
    params.permit(:role, :is_add, :event_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Despite this the controller#action is still wrong (and thus seems to be adding in the `id` param)

```
Started PUT "/events/add_or_rm_role?event_id=_ceEY&is_add=false&role=3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-31 21:37:45 -0400
Processing by EventsController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"_ceEY", "is_add"=>"false", "role"=>"3", "id"=>"add_or_rm_role"}
```

Where did I go wrong (server was restarted)?

**UPDATE**

If I change the order of my Rails routing (giving add_or_rm_role higher precedence), the correct controller is matched. Is this because my Event IDs are string?

```
  namespace :events do
      put :add_or_rm_role, to: 'participants#add_or_rm_role'
  end
  resources :events
```

Now the correct action is called but an error is thrown before it can finish: `NameError (uninitialized constant Participant):`

**UPDATE**

`NameError (uninitialized constant Participant):` was being thrown because I was attempting to authorize (via CanCanCan) a non-resource at the top of Events::ParticipantsController with `load_and_authorize_resource`. Since the model is namespaced I need to specify the resource model manually: `load_and_authorize_resource class: "Event::Participant"`

**UPDATE**

After fixing all of the above, I recieved the error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'event_id' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f791dcbe240>):`, which I thought has something to do with the strong params, but ended up being caused by using dot notation: `event_participants_params.event_id` is broken but `event_participants_params[:event_id]` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your routes

```
PUT    /events/:id/add_or_rm_role(.:format) events/participants#add_or_rm_role #This one looks good!
```

`events/participants#add_or_rm_role` translates to an action called `add_or_rm_role` on a namespaced controller called `Events::ParticipantsController`, but this controller doesn't exist.

You do have a `ParticipantsController::EventsController`, but I don't think that's what you're intending either. That translates to an `EventsController` class nested inside of a `ParticipantsController` module. I would rename that simply to `ParticipantsController`.

It also looks like you're trying to send an `id: @event.id` to the controller, but the controller is expecting a param called `event_id`.

I think you're looking to `nest` this path, not `namespace` it. I think this change to your routing will get you on the right track

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events do
    put '/add_or_rm_role', as: :add_or_rm_role, to: 'participants#add_or_rm_role'
  end
end
```

It will generate this route

```
event_add_or_rm_role PUT    /events/:event_id/add_or_rm_role(.:format) participants#add_or_rm_role
```

You'll now have a route helper method `event_add_or_rm_role` with an `event_id` param in the URL, sending the put request to `ParticipantsController#add_or_rm_role`. Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome catch on the controller naming issues! Writing the question had helped me find the routing issue but that was still stumping me. Could you elaborate a bit on the semantic differences btw namespacing and nesting? Which one would you want to use in different situations? I suppose namespacing may be better if there are a lot of related event models/controllers, but otherwise nesting might be better? Is pointing a nested/member route to: a different controller bad form?