# Rails route going to wrong controller action only when there is a rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I am trying to add a very simple API to an existing Rails 3.2 web app (using [this](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/) guide). I am running into an issue where my route is executing an existing action instead of my new one but only if I try to `rescue_from` an exception. Here's the code (obviously not my real code, but keeps essential elements):

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :merchants, only: [:index] # existing route
# rake routes generates: goodies GET /goodies(.:format) goodies#index

# http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.my_app.v#{@version}") || @default
  end
end

namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
    resources :goodies, only: [:index] # new route
  end
end
# rake routes generates: api_goodies GET /api/goodies(.:format) api/v1/goodies#index {:format=>"json"}
```

.

```
# app/controllers/goodies_controller.rb

class GoodiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @goodies = Goody.order(:name)
  end
end
```

.

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb

class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  include ActionController::Rendering
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  append_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views"

  before_filter :authenticate
  rescue_from NotAuthenticated, :deny_access # it works if I comment-out this line

  private

  def authenticate
    # fail NotAuthenticated if not authenticated
  end

  def deny_access
    render json: { error_message: 'Forbidden' }, status: 403
  end
end
```

.

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/goodies_controller.rb

class Api::V1::GoodiesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    @goodies = Goody.order(:name)
  end
end
```

Here are my scenarios when I send a `GET my_app.dev/api/goodies` request that has the `Accept` header value set to `application/vnd.my_app.v1`:

1. (*with* the `rescue_from`)

   1. Without auth creds - I get the results from the view used by `goodies#index` instead of the one used by `api/v1/goodies#index`
   2. With auth creds - same
2. (*without* the `rescue_from`)

   1. Without auth creds - I get the standard development Rails 500 error page showing that a `NotAuthenticated` error was raised
   2. With auth creds - I get the results from the view used by `api/v1/goodies#index`

For scenario #1, I know it's not just using the wrong view because if I put a `fail` in `api/v1/goodies#index`, I still get the results for `goodies#index`.

I don't think this is relevant, but I'm using `*.json.jbuilder` views.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457076/nested-namespace-route-going-to-wrong-controller) post, which is similar, but specific to `rescue_from`. I haven't tried the OP's comment, but I don't think I should have to change my controller name to make this work.

Comment: `@default || value` is pretty fishy. If you give that class a default, it will never attempt to evaluate the incoming value. You need `value || @default`.

Comment: @meagar good catch! :) but still doesn't solve my current problem... :(